# Creating multiple instances of Imported MEF parts

Tags: c#, .net, mef

Currently my WPF application imports a part like this

```
[Import(typeof(ILedPanel)]
public ILedPanel Panel { get; set; }
```

But this gives ma a single intance of the class that implements ILedPanel.
What I really want to do is have the ability to create as many instances
that I need. Please note there is only one Export for ILedPanel included
with the software at any given time.

(If I use an import with List that gives me one instance
for every class implementing ILedPanel)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good way but I simply went with Activator.CreateInstance(Panel.GetType());

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't "built in" support for this in MEF today, but before reverting to Service Locator, you might find some inspiration here: http://blogs.msdn.com/nblumhardt/archive/2008/12/27/container-managed-application-design-prelude-where-does-the-container-belong.aspx

The essential idea is that you 'import' the container into the component that needs to do dynamic instantiation.

More direct support for this scenario is something we're exploring.

Nick

**UPDATE:** MEF now has experimental support for this. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/nblumhardt/archive/2009/08/28/dynamic-part-instantiation-in-mef.aspx) for more information.

Comment: UPDATE: this feature has made its way into MEF "Preview 7" as PartCreator<T> - see the MEF wiki for information (http://mef.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=PartCreator&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: But only for Silverlight it would seem

Comment: This was added to Preview 8 for non-Silverlight and then pulled from Preview 9! Grrr.

Answer (score 11):

All of the other answers are pretty old, so they don't mention a relatively new feature in MEF called [`ExportFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382807(v=vs.110).aspx). This generic class allows you to import `ExportFactory<ILedPanel>` and create as many instances as you like whenever you need them, so your code would look like this:

```
[Import(typeof(ILedPanel)]
public ExportFactory<ILedPanel> PanelFactory { get; set; }

public ILedPanel CreateNewLedPanelInstance()
{
    return PanelFactory.CreateExport().Value;
}
```

This method also satisfies any imports that created part has. You can read more about using the `ExportFactory` class [here](https://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PartCreator).

Comment: That is basically the build in solution for a mechanism I was about to suggest, anybody can build self. You actually create a factory class that has a injectable property. Whenever you call MEF's populate object method, it gets a new instance that it then can return. A build in ExportFactory is certainly nicer.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this is what Nicolas is referring to, but you could import a Factory class rather than an instance class, like this:

```
[Import(typeof(ILedPanelFactory)]
public ILedPanelFactory PanelFactory { get; set; }
```

...and then later in your code...

```
ILedPanel panel = PanelFactory.BuildPanel();
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless I misunderstand the question, it looks like it would be solved by simply using a CreationPolicy.NonShared.

This assumes that the code declaring the Panel exists everywhere you want a panel. You would get a new instance of ILedPanel in every instance of every class that had this declaration (the import).

Comment: That's true. But there is only one class that implements ILedPanel with any distribution of the software. So that's a single instance... it's not clean of course

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the shapes game sample that comes with MEF, there is the ShapeFactory class:

```
[Export]
public class ShapeFactory
{
    private readonly Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    [Import]
    private ICompositionService CompositionService { get; set; }

    public IShape GetRandomShape()
    {
        var shapeRetriever = new ShapeRetriever();

        CompositionService.SatisfyImports(shapeRetriever);

        int randomIndex = random.Next(shapeRetriever.PossibleShapes.Length);

        return shapeRetriever.PossibleShapes[randomIndex].GetExportedObject();
    }

    private class ShapeRetriever
    {
        [ImportMany(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
        public Export<IShape, IShapeMetadata>[] PossibleShapes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which demonstrates creating a random shape instances "on demand"... I would think in your scenario you could do something similar without the selection of a random implementation, as you suggest there would be only one implementation of ILedPanel registered.

Answer (score 2):

i think you mean you want to use MEF in this instance like a service locator rather than a dependency injection container. Try looking at examples for ValueResolver