# How should I create plugins with multiple instances in C#?

Tags: c#, plugins, mef

My ultimate goal is to load controls as plugins, for use as DocumentContent in AvalonDock. As a result, I will need to be able to create multiple instances of these controls, and I would prefer to do so with as limited overhead for the Plugin creators as possible.

My initial intention was to use MEF to locate and manage my plugins, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947807/creating-multiple-instances-of-imported-mef-parts) seems to imply that, at least at this point in time, MEF might not be intended for this.

Should I be using another solution (is the domain of DI containers, or MEF specifically, considered limited to providing *instances* of classes, and is there another solution that maps better to my problem), or should I use the suggested solutions (such as using reflection to clone instances, or requiring plugin creators to supply factory methods/objects - seemingly hackish) to work with/around MEF (or alternatively, is there a simple way to configure MEF to accomplish this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MEF's latest previews includes a type specifically for this scenario - see the blog post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/nblumhardt/archive/2009/08/28/dynamic-part-instantiation-in-mef.aspx or more info on the MEF wiki: http://mef.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=PartCreator&referringTitle=Home.